# Turn sound off in Opera (Notification Desktop) with coding in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, notifications, opera

I use Notification desktop and I need to turn the sound off.

in Google Chrome and Firefox the sound is off but in Opera is on.

[Test Notification](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/)

In the GUID is saying:

> At the time of writing no browser has support for this option.

[image]

But why the sound is working in opera?

My code in JavaScript:

```
function notifyBrowser(title, desc, url) {
  if (!Notification) {
    console.log('Desktop notifications not available in your browser..');
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
    Notification.requestPermission();
  } else {
    var notification = new Notification(title, {
      icon: "/img.png",
      body: desc,
      tag: 'Notification Desktop',
    });

    // Remove the notification from Notification Center when clicked.
    notification.onclick = function() {
      window.open("https://www.website.com");
    };
    // Callback function when the notification is closed.
    notification.onclose = function() {
      console.log('Notification closed');
    };
  }
}
```

I'm adding sound option like this but nothing changed

```
var notification = new Notification(title, {
  icon: "/img.png",
  body: desc,
  tag: 'Notification Desktop',
  sound: "",
  // or sound : null,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The option `sound` isn't listed in [specification](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#silent-preference-flag). It imho only existed in the draft of the standard.

Some browser have still support of the `sound` option, but you must not use or relay on it anymore.

You have to use `silent` and `vibrate` to define if the system specific sound has to be played or not.

But the `silent` option still does not work everywhere.